# Generate a pseudo random 6 character string from an integer

Tags: php, hash, radix

I am trying to resolve the following problem via PHP. The aim is to generate a unique 6-character string based on an integer seed and containing a predefined range of characters.  The second requirement is that the string must appear random (so if code 1 were 100000, it is not acceptable for code 2 to be 100001, and 3 100002)

The range of characters is:

- Uppercase A-Z excluding: B, I, O, S and Z
- 0-9 excluding: 0, 1, 2, 5, 8

So that would be a total of 26 characters if I am not mistaken. My first idea would to be encoding from base 10 to base 24 starting at number 7962624. So do 7962624 + seed, and then base24 encode that number.

This gives me the characters 0-N.  If I replace the resulting string in the following fashion, I then meet the first criteria:

```
B=P, I=Q, 0=R, 1=T, 2=U, 5=V, 8=W
```

So at this point, my codes will look something like this:

```
1=TRRRR, 2=TRRRT, 3=TRRRU
```

So my question to you gurus is: ***How can I make a method that behaves consistently (so the return string for a given integer is always the same) and meets the 2 requirements above?*** I have spent 2 full days on this now and short of dumping 700,000,000 codes into a database and retrieving them randomly I'm all out of ideas.

Stephen

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using this string for? Have you considered collisions?

Comment: It is going to be a human readable way to access a resource identified by the integer. Unfortunately I'm under NDA so can't tell you exactly why but it is not dissimilar to shortURLs.

Comment: Re: collision my original solution was base encoding as I believe this is impossible with that method

Comment: That's fine. I understand not saying the specifics. I really just wanted to know if you were doing your own home-brew cryptography. If the number has to be secret, I think 6 characters is not enough. Someone could just try random ones, and they could easily get a valid one after a few tries, not to mention that you aren't hashing this number, but rather encoding/encrypting it. The difference being that is reversible, which sounds like it could be a concern, is that correct? I ask about collisions, because with a true hashing method, this could be a concern.

Comment: Ah, np.  No it isn't intended to be a cypher, perhaps I tagged the OP incorrectly, it is just a means of using a 6-digit string to reference an integer.  function(int) has to consistently return the same value, but it does not have to be reversible, nor is it an issue if it is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a reasonably random looking sequence if you take your input sequence 1,2,3... and apply a linear map modulo a prime number. The number of unique codes is limited to the prime number so you should choose a large one. The resulting codes will be unique as long as you choose a multiplier that's not divisible by the prime.

Here's an example: With 6 characters you can make 26<sup>6</sup>=308915776 unique strings, so a suitable prime number could be 308915753. This function therefore will generate over 300.000.000 unique codes:

```
function encode($num) {
    $scrambled = (240049382*$num + 37043083) % 308915753;
    return base_convert($scrambled, 10, 26);
}
```

Make sure that you run this on 64bit PHP though, otherwise the multiplication will overflow. On 32bit you'll have to use `bcmath`. The codes generated for the numbers 1 through 9 are:

```
n89a2d
hdh4jo
biopb9
5o6k2k
3eek5
k8m9aj
ee4424
8jbojf
2ojjb0
```

All that's left is filling in the initial 0s that are sometimes missing and replacing the letters and numbers so that none of the forbidden characters are produced.

As you can see, there's no obvious pattern, but someone with some time on their hands, enough motivation and with access to a few of this codes will be able to find out what's going on. A safer alternative is using an encryption algorithm with a small block size, such as [Skip32](https://github.com/nlenepveu/Skip32).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious. I understand that you used 240049382 and 37043083 for the linear mapping, but how did you choose them? I understand the prime you picked for the modulus choice though.

Comment: Just type in random digits.

Comment: Ha, I gotta say I am a little disappointed with that response, but I accept it. I was expecting them to be carefully chosen for this purpose using advanced mathematics, but the answer was basically: "smashed my head on the keyboard". Good answer though.

Comment: This is almost definitely the accepted answer, but would it be possible to explain what the effects are of the 3 numbers in the algorithm.  It seems obvious that the 3rd is a large prime, but what are the other two's purpose?? What is the effect of making them larger/smaller, and why did you choose the ones you did

Comment: Given `(a*x+b)%p`, the `a` is the difference between subsequent numbers. Making it large ensures that you won't see a code like xxxxxx, xxxxxy, xxxxxz. The `b` is needed to make the start point of the sequence hard to guess; without it the code for x=0 would be 0, and the code for x=1 would give you `a`. Using both you get something that looks hard to predict and random.

Comment: Heh it is so obvious when I look back at the formula.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Also, you want to pick values for a and b which share no common factors (relatively prime).